# Why getYear() return 2018 for Date(2019, 1, 1)?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting the wrong value for year when using `getYear()`.

I have a cell with "01/01/2019" or `=Date(2019, 1, 1)` value and when I write a custom function and use `getYear()`, it returns 2018, not 2019. Why?

```
function textMESCAT(data) {
var mesos = ['Gener', 'Febrer', 'Març', 'Abril', 'Maig', 'Juny', 'Juliol', 'Agost', 'Setembre', 'Octubre', 'Novembre', 'Desembre'];

var textmes = mesos[data.getMonth()] + '-' + data.getYear();

return textmes;
}
```

I expected output Gener-2019. The output is Desembre-2018, but that is wrong, it presents the day before.

Comment: Because your local timezone is 1 (or more) hours behind UTC so it's still something like 2018-12-31 23:00:00. I'm not familiar with google apps script so I can't tell you how to handle Local Time vs. UTC.

Comment: Add this as an answer to your question - not a comment.

Comment: The answer has been useful! I've made some changes in code and It works. function textMCAT(data) { var mesos = ['Gener', 'Febrer', 'Març', 'Abril', 'Maig', 'Juny', 'Juliol', 'Agost', 'Setembre', 'Octubre', 'Novembre', 'Desembre']; var meslocal = Utilities.formatDate(data, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "M"); var anylocal = Utilities.formatDate(data, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy"); var textmes = mesos[parseInt(meslocal)-1] + '-' + anylocal; return textmes; }

Comment: @Josep Add it as a answer below

Answer (score -2):

I receive "Gener-119" when calling textMESCAT(new Date(2019, 1, 1)).

Try using Date.prototype.getFullYear() instead of Date.prototype.getYear() since the latter is unstable.